# get exception from func that has func as an param

Tags: javascript

I have one function a that accepts a function `func` as an argument and returns a new function

how to catch error thrown from a function in function a, because i want to return null from function a when function returns exception. In below case also

Comment: Surround it with a try catch? Might as well just return null instead of even throwing the error in the first place I think.

Comment: i have tried but not going into catch  . const wrap=(func)=>{ try{
  return func;}catch(e){return null;}
}

Comment: return boolean otherwise also, as simply `return ++count !== 3` also if you will catch the error on `3` it will continue after that like no errors on 4,5...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return a new function that calls `func` wrapped in a `try..catch`, and remembers whether it has error'd before:

```
const a = func => {
    let hasThrown = false;

    return function () {
        if (hasThrown) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return func(...arguments);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
            hasThrown = true;
            return null;
        }
    };
};
```

```js
const a = func => {
  let hasThrown = false;

  return function() {
    if (hasThrown) {
      return null;
    }
   
    try {
      return func(...arguments);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      hasThrown = true;
      return null;
    }
  };
};

const getMyName = (name) => {
  if (name === "jos") {
    throw new Error(`${name} is wrong`);
  }
  return `${name} is yummy`;
};

const getName = a(getMyName);
console.log(getName("harry"));
console.log(getName("garry"));
console.log(getName("jos"));
console.log(getName("jon"));
```

Comment: i have to return null if function once throws exception?

Comment: Thanks so much. what is the meaning of "...arguments". and how it works

Answer (score 0):

You could surround `getCount()` inside `try` and `catch`

```
try {
    getCount()
} 
catch(e){
    console.log(e)
}
```